# Image moving without touching - xcode / swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a Snake Game.
An important thing to do this is that the Snake keeps moving. For example, if scroll with my finger to right, the snake has to start moving right and he has to keep doing that.
Well, I created an array with 4 items

```
var moves = [false, false, false, false]
//moves[0] -> Up
//moves[1] -> Down
//moves[2] -> Right
//moves[3] -> Left
```

E.g. When I scroll left, all the items in the array turns to false and then the third element turn to true.

All this code is located in the "GameScene.swift" file.
If I change the player position like this...

```
if moves[0]==true {
   player.position.y += 56 
   //player is the "head" of the snake
   //"56" is the dimension of each position
}
```

...and I put all this code into the touchesMoved function...

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}
```

...the snake moves ONLY If i scroll.
For this reason, I thought I could just take all this code out of the function... but I can't. It just says "Expected declaration".

So, what do I have to do?

Actually I don't know which part of my code would be helpful to solve this problem...
If you need more information just ask!

Thx you for have read all this stuff by the way ^ - ^

Comment: As you say, the snake should just move some amount every so often, even if the user NEVER touches the screen. So where is your code that makes that happen? You should do that first, and only then worry about change of direction

Comment: I'm really new on swift and I'm trying to learn the language. For the direction it's easy, I've already done this game using python instead... But when I used python I just had a HUGE while loop where I put all the code. So, to increase the position of the snake, I used to take the X and Y of the snake, increase them (if move up add 10 to Y) and then re-print the head.
But on swift I can't do that because there's not a big while where I can put this code. So, is there a function I should call? Or am I using the wrong file? Because letting the code "free" is not possible as I saw

Comment: The usual thing is to run a Timer or CADisplayLink to signal that you need to generate a new frame of the animation. But if you have elected to use SpriteKit you’d likely use an SKAction.

Comment: By the way please do not worry about language when all of this has really to do with framework.

Answer (score 0):

SKAction was what I needed, thx matt.
At the end I did this:

```
func moveSnake(){
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y )
        var playerX:CGFloat = 0
        var playerY:CGFloat = 0
        if moves[0]==true{
            playerY += 56
        }
        if moves[1]==true{
            playerY -= 56
        }
        if moves[2]==true{
            playerX += 56
        }
        if moves[3]==true{
            playerX -= 56
        }
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: playerX + player.position.x, y: playerY + player.position.y)
        let moveIt = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration:0.1)
        player.run(moveIt)
    }



    func moveItDamn(){
        let move = SKAction.run(moveSnake)
        let waitToMove = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.01)
        let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([move, waitToMove])
        let moveForever = SKAction.repeatForever(moveSequence)
        self.run(moveForever)
    }
```

What am I doing here?

1. I create a new function called "moveSnake()"
2. Now I declare some variables and constants:

   - startPoint is where the player is... the previous point. His X is equal to his xPosition and his Y is equal to his yPosition
   - now I'll declare another constant: endPoint. This constant contains the X e Y of the position. But, before, I need to add or subtract 56 (dimension of the head) to the X and Y of the snake
   - for this reason, I create 2 variables: playerX and playerY (type CGFloat, numbers)
   - now I check where is the snake going. The moves[] array contains 4 bool item. If I scroll up with my finger, the first element of the array turns true. If I move down, all the elements inside the array turns false and then the second one turns true, etc etc...  If the snake is going up, I'll ADD 56 to his Y, if he's going down, I'll subtract 56 to his Y (the same for right and left)
   - now I create another SKAction constant: moveIt.  In this constant is stored an action, the move action. Basically, I say to my program to move the player from the startPosition to the endPosition and to do it in 0.1 seconds.
   - now I just say to the program to run the moveIt constant, I tell him to move the snake.

3. It's not over, I also need to create a sequence so you can run again and again this code. For this reason, I declare a new function: moveItDamn

   - first of all, I create a constant which contains an action: this constant will be used to run the moveSnake function
   - then I create a "wait constant" called waitToMove of the duration of 0.01 seconds
   - I create a sequence:  move and then waitToMove
   - now I tell the program to run this thing forever and I put this action inside another constant: moveForever
   - last thing, I tell the function to run this constant: self.run(moveForever)
4. Now, to make all this think work I have to call my last function (moveItDamn) inside the GameScene class. And done!

Well, I don't know if this is the best way to do what I wanted and I'd appreciate other tips. I'm a total beginner and I'm having my difficulties to learn the language, but when I found a way to do this, I decided to share my work with other beginners like me :)